Issue Running React Native Expo App After Migrating from SDK 49 to 50
I recently upgraded my React Native project from Expo SDK 49 to SDK 50, and I'm having trouble getting my app to run.
After upgrading to Expo SDK 50, my app no longer runs as expected.
{
  "name": "abclimited",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "dev-android-build": "eas build --profile development --platform android",
    "dev-ios-build": "eas build --profile development --platform ios",
    "preview-android-build": "eas build --profile preview --platform android",
    "preview-ios-build": "eas build --profile preview --platform ios",
    "production-android-build": "eas build --platform android",
    "production-ios-build": "eas build --platform ios",
    "dev-client": "expo start -- --reset-cache --dev-client",
    "production-build-all": "eas build --platform all",
    "submit-ios-build": "eas submit --platform ios --latest",
    "submit-android-build": "eas submit --platform android --latest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-voice/voice": "^3.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.21",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.5",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.9.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-native": "^0.73.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-echarts-wrapper": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.8",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.8",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "3.22.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "redux": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.13",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Updated all dependencies to their compatible versions with SDK 50.
Cleared the cache using expo start -- --reset-cache.
Checked the official Expo migration guide for any additional steps.
npm run dev-client -> when scan in physical device in expo go -> app is not opening
Rebuilt the app using eas build for Android and build is unsuccessful.
